# PHP - 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: php, android, nginx, android-json

I've been trying to make an Android app which will have the function to create new user profiles and store the various details(email, password, etc.) to a remote server. Now, I'm using JSON to upload the user data to my remote server. But, the problem is, when I'm trying upload a high resolution image to my server for the user's profile picture, it is giving me a **"413 Request Enitity Too Large"** error. Now, I read online that these kind of errors can be fixed by editing the `php.ini` and `nginx.conf`, but the problem is, though I managed to change the values in the `php.ini`, I can't even find the `nginx.conf` file on my server! Even though my server host claims that `nginx` is installed on all their servers. What should I do in such a situation? Is there any way to edit the `nginx.conf` programmatically using php?

Here's the output I'm getting:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Request Entity Too Large</h1>
The requested resource<br />/enter_name.php<br />
does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided inthe request exceeds the capacity limit.
</body></html>
```

**Any help on this issue shall be highly appreciated**

Answer (score 0):

You can check nginx config with this command:

```
nginx -t
```

Config file location will be in result, for example:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Then set client_max_body_size directive in this config:

```
client_max_body_size 20m;
```

See [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) for details.